# Lost passport and overstaying in Kuwait?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, filipino-citizens, overstaying, kuwait

I'm on a visit visa in Kuwait, I lost my passport, can I exit Kuwait using travel documents issued by our embassy? I am filipino, overstaying, we have an embassy in Kuwait.

Comment: What citizen are you? What country's passport DID you possess? Does your country have an embassy in Kuwait? The more information the better...

Comment: Please edit your response into your question. Also you mentioned overstaying in the title, but nowhere in your question - can you clarify this?

Comment: Am from philippines, i am overstaying in kuwait

Comment: Am filipino, overstaying in KuwAit

Comment: Didn't the embassy, when you went there to get your paperwork, give you directions on how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

If you overstayed, noone will stop you on the way out, they will be quite happy to see you go. You'll have a problem the next time you try to enter. The embassy issued travel document will be fine, that's what it's for.

Comment: I don't know about Kuwait, but in several other countries (eg I've seen it happen in Russia) they'll stop you, make you pay a fine, and THEN let you go.

Comment: In the GCC countries that's the case, they will be happy to let you go. In saudi they even will be happy to pay for your ticket if you go to the immigration office (after some time detention till they finish the process of issuing the ticket).